# Sphinx documentation processor extension works differently for HTML and LaTeX output?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a simple Sphinx extension as follows:

```py
from docutils import nodes
from docutils.parsers.rst import directives
from sphinx.util.compat import Directive

class testnode(nodes.Element):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(testnode, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self['foo'] = '?'

def visit_testnode_latex(self, node):
    self.body.append('Test: %s' % node['foo'])

def depart_testnode_latex(self, node):
    pass

def visit_testnode_html(self, node):
    self.body.append('<p>Test: %s</p>' % node['foo'])

def depart_testnode_html(self, node):
    pass

class TestDirective(Directive):
    has_content = False
    required_arguments = 0
    optional_arguments = 0
    final_argument_whitespace = False
    option_spec = {
        'foo': directives.unchanged,
    }

    def run(self):
        node = testnode()
        node['foo'] = self.options.get('foo')
        return [node]

def setup(app):
    app.add_directive("testdirective", TestDirective)
    app.add_node(testnode,
                 html=(visit_testnode_html,
                       depart_testnode_html),
                 latex=(visit_testnode_latex,
                        depart_testnode_latex))
```

Given a document containing

```
.. testdirective::
   :foo: bar
```

the HTML output contains »Test: bar« but the LaTeX output contains »Test: ?« (the default value). I checked that `node['foo']` has the correct value after the assignment in `TestDirective.run()`, but that does not appear to stick around until the LaTeX writer runs.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

After stepping through the LaTeX writer for Sphinx I found the problem here.  It's the way in which you're setting a default for the `'foo'` keyword in the `testnode` initializer.

There's a point in the LaTeX writer that it does a deepcopy of your entire document tree in order to inline it in another tree.  A deepcopy on an `Element` node initializes a new node of the same class and passes all the attributes and contents of the original node through the constructor.  So when your `testnode` gets copied your constructor overrides the original 'foo' attribute that's passed into the constructor.  Instead write it like this and it should work:

```
class testnode(nodes.Element):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(testnode, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'foo' not in self:
            self['foo'] = '?'
```

This will prevent your default from overriding any explicit value for the attribute that's been passed to the constructor.  There are several other variations possible.